# Socket-Management in Nginx with Flask - Why is Cross-Origin Request Blocked?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, socket.io, gunicorn

I want to create a socket in Flask-SocketIO through Nginx and Unicorn. The following configuration works on *localhost* without Nginx.

When I access the web application through Nginx in Chrome, i get the error:

> Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.
>   http://52.34.18.48:6419/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1454455363683-6

When I access the web application through Nginx in Firefox, I get the error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://52.34.18.48:6419/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1454464333740-25. (Reason: CORS request failed).

This is how I initialize the socket connection in JavaScript:

```
import io from "socket.io-client"

const socketUrl = 'http://' + document.domain + ':6419' + '/FlaskApp'
const socket = io(socketUrl);

export default socket;
```

My Nginx config file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 52.34.18.48;
    error_log /var/www/Flaskapp/nginx_errorlog.log;
    access_log /var/www/Flaskapp/nginx_accesslog.log;

    root /var/www/Flaskapp;

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6419/socket.io;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6419;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

The Gunicorn command I used is:

```
gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 -b 127.0.0.1:6419 flask_app:application
```

I wrapped the socket in the Flask application like this.

```
from flask_app import application
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

socketio = SocketIO(application)
```

Why do I get this error via Nginx but not when connecting via localhost? How can I access the socket.io via Nginx correctly?